# Is there an option to do multi mapping for QueryFirstAsync or QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync in Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am trying to map the object from sql to multiple objects in C#. How do I multi map in the case of having QueryFirstAsync and QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync?

I have tried similar to the process in QueryAsync or Query.

```
ClassA record = 
await this.dbConnection.QueryFirstAsync<ClassA, ClassB, ClassA>(
sql,                   
(a, b) =>
{
  a.Id = b.Id;                                                                           
  return a;
},
splitOn: "Id",
param: new
{
  memberId
});
```

I expect the successful build but it does not work for QueryFirstAsync or QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync.

Comment: what's the build error ?

Comment: Also how about calling `QueryAsync` with multi map and on the result call `FirstOrDefault()`, that would not have any compilation issues

Comment: @MrinalKamboj your recommendation fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I have posted the same with detailed answer, you may accept it, since the issue stands resolved using the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Current Issue:**

You are trying to use multi mapping with the dapper functions, `QueryFirstAsync` and `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync`, but none of their overload supports Mutli-Mapping as done by `QueryAsync`, pasting the definition from the Dapper code:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>(this IDbConnection cnn, 
CommandDefinition command, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map, string splitOn = "Id") => 
MultiMapAsync<TFirst, TSecond, DontMap, DontMap, DontMap, DontMap, DontMap, TReturn>(cnn, 
command, map, splitOn);
```

which calls `MultiMapAsync`, which utilize the `SplitOn` value to create multi map default being `Id`

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> MultiMapAsync<TReturn>(this IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type[] types, Func<object[], TReturn> map, string splitOn)
        {
            if (types.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("you must provide at least one type to deserialize");
            }

            object param = command.Parameters;
            var identity = new Identity(command.CommandText, command.CommandType, cnn, types[0], param?.GetType(), types);
            var info = GetCacheInfo(identity, param, command.AddToCache);
            bool wasClosed = cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed;
            try
            {
                if (wasClosed) await cnn.TryOpenAsync(command.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                using (var cmd = command.TrySetupAsyncCommand(cnn, info.ParamReader))
                using (var reader = await ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallbackAsync(cmd, wasClosed, CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.SingleResult, command.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    var results = MultiMapImpl(null, default(CommandDefinition), types, map, splitOn, reader, identity, true);
                    return command.Buffered ? results.ToList() : results;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (wasClosed) cnn.Close();
            }
        }
```

> **Solution:**

Use standard `QueryAsync`, which has an overload which takes `SplitOn` and on the final result call `FirstorDefault`, since the result of the Dapper query is `IEnumerable<T>`, therefore any of the standard Linq extensions methods can be called